# Bell like tone on my octave mandolin

Tags: sound, octave, mandolin

While playing chords on my octave manolin, I'm hearing a strange bell-like almost harmonic sound mixed in with the note.

Comment: Have a look at https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=wolf+tone

Comment: It would be rather helpful to get a sound sample,  a definition of the open string pitches and the notes or chords which lead to this perceived tone, and so on.   You say you're playing a chord but then say the overtone is mixed with "the note" . Which is it?  Does anyone else hear it (could be a problem with your inner ear)?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Are you wondering what causes this, or perhaps how to fix it?

Comment: could also be hearing the chorusing effect of the string courses. I find it much more noticeable on my Octave than on my soprano.